# Comparing columns with two worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheets. One with the account number and sub account (shown here):

```
   B                 C                      D
   ACCOUNT           SUBNUMBER ACCT         DESCRIPTION
   580101            1                      (where formula should be)   
   580101            2
   580102            1
   580102            2
```

The second worksheet shows (accts):

```
    B                C                      D
    ACCOUNT          SUBNUMBER ACCT         DESCRIPTION
    580100           0                      Provision for Bad Debt IP
    580101           0                      Provision for Bad Debt OP
    580101           1                      Bad Debt Mcare IP
    580101           2                      Bad Debt Mcare OP
```

I want to be able to create a formula that if (Sheet 1) Column A and Column B is found in the accts (second worksheet) then the description should be displayed.

For example:
On the first row it shows `580100  1`. Then the description should be "Bad Debt Mcare IP".

Comment: I do but not well versed.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to create a unique key on each worksheet that is a combination of the id and subaccount numbers using the concatenate operation &

For example in a new column (unique key) just add A1&B1 which will create a unique key. Its then easy to do a vlookup on the data to get the description you want.